# Why doesn’t ( display: block; ) doesn’t work on the menu item?

Tags: html, css

I have this side menu (image below) which needs to be a `block/column` but `display: block` doesn’t work for some reason!?
Here is the CSS and the HTML can you tell what's wrong.

Screenshot here

[image: screenshot]

PS. I don't want to do it with the `<br>` tags, rather doing it through CSS.

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

body h4 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.category-tree {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1100px;
}

.left-menu-categories {
  float: left;
}

body div nav ul li a {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.left-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="category-tree">
    <h3 class="cat-title">Categories</h3>
    <nav class="left-menu">
      <ul class="left-menu-categories">
        <li class=""><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" title="Estate">Title</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Kindly check again because it is working here.

Comment: why do you want to declare `display: block;` in the first place? `ul`and `li` are block level elements by default.

Comment: I need to list those one under another! So it should be Title under Title under title.

Comment: it is listed below each other. And like I said, `dispaly: block` is the default value of `ul` and `li` elements. We can't reproduce the error you explaining.

Comment: Wow, thats weird! I am on chrome and I see it like in the screenshot!?

Comment: @tacoshy The default display value of li elements is `list-item`, not `block`.

Comment: @Alohci qhich is true. But `list-item` is still a block level element. The tiny difference is that is also shows a bullet point. However switching from `list-item` to `block` does exactly nothing as it remains a block level element and the bullet points is not removed either.